# Mvc .net Session Expiration issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I am working on MVC.net. In my application what i have done is after 15mnts I have displayed popup on the screen to warn that the session is about to expire. and if user click on the "ok" button then an async request is sent to server to refresh the session. but it is not actually refreshing the session. What could be the reason?
Can any body has some idea to handle this?

Comment: please post the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could post the code you're using (to send the Async request, and also the code that runs on the server side).

As a shot in the dark, if you're using some sort of web service, then you might need to explicitly turn on session support, eg:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public void Ping()
{
}
```